# Extracting articles from New York Post by using Python and New York Post API

Tags: python

I am trying to create a corpus of text documents via the New york Times API (articles concerning terrorist attacks) on Python.

I am aware that the NYP API do not provide the full body text, but provides the URL from which I can scrape the article. So the idea is to extract the "web_url" parameters from the API and consequently scrape the full body article.

I am trying to use the NYT API library on Python with these lines:

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI

api = articleAPI("*Your Key*")
articles = api.search( q = 'terrorist attack')

print(articles['response'],['docs'],['web_url'])
```

But I cannot extract the "web_url" or the articles. All I get is this output:

```
{'meta': {'time': 19, 'offset': 10, 'hits': 0}, 'docs': []} ['docs'] ['web_url']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the `nytimesarticle` module itself. For example, see the following:

```
>>> articles = api.search(q="trump+women+accuse", begin_date=20161001)
>>> print(articles)
{'response': {'docs': [], 'meta': {'offset': 0, 'hits': 0, 'time': 21}}, 'status': 'OK', 'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2013 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.'}
```

But if I use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) (as is used in the module) to access the API directly, I get the results I'm looking for:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=trump+women+accuse&begin_date=20161001&api-key=XXXXX")
>>> data = r.json()
>>> len(data["response"]["docs"])
10
```

meaning that 10 articles were returned (the full value of `data` is 16kb, so I won't include it all here). Contrast that to the response from `api.search()`, where `articles["response"]["docs"]` is an empty list.

`nytimesarticle.py` is only 115 lines long, so it's pretty straightforward to debug. Printing the value of the URL sent to the API reveals this:

```
>>> articles = api.search(q="trump+women+accuse", begin_date=20161001)
https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=b'trump+women+accuse'&begin_date=20161001&api-key=XXXXX
#                                                          ^^ THIS
```

The [offending code](https://github.com/evansherlock/nytimesarticle/blob/89f551699ffb11f71b47271246d350a1043e9326/nytimesarticle.py#L29-L42) encodes every string parameter to UTF-8, which makes it a `bytes` object. This is not necessary, and wrecks the constructed URL as shown above. Fortunately, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/evansherlock/nytimesarticle/pull/2) that fixes this:

```
>>> articles = api.search(q="trump+women+accuse", begin_date=20161001)
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date=20161001&q=trump+women+accuse&api-key=XXXXX
>>> len(articles["response"]["docs"])
10
```

This also allows for other string parameters such as `sort="newest"` to be used, as the bytes formatting was causing an error previously.

Comment: But how come even by changing the URI I cannot access the web_url parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The comma in the print statement separates what is printed.

You'll want something like this

```
articles['response']['docs']['web_url']
```

But `'docs': []` is both an array and empty, so above line won't work, so you could try

```
articles = articles['response']['docs']
for article in articles:
    print(article['web_url'])
```

Comment: If you're interested, see my answer above. There's actually an issue with the `nytimesarticle` module itself that caused incorrect query strings to be assembled from bytes objects before being sent to the API, therefore giving back errors or no matches because the query was `q=b'your+query+here'` instead of `q=your+query+here`. A PR was submitted a year ago to fix it, but hasn't been merged yet...

Comment: @MattDMo Gotcha. I did find it strange that the docs were empty. Glad we can stay relevant with the news, though, here on SO ;)

Comment: yup, just in case anyone has been living under a rock (with an internet connection) for the last several years :)